# How can you find the "majority colors" of an image using PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

How can I calculate what the majority colors of an image are in PHP? I'd prefer to group different shades of a similar color into a single bucket, so for example all shades of blue are just counted as "blue".

In other words, I'd like a function that takes an image and returns a simple array similar to:

```
"blue":90%, "white":10%
```

No need for high accuracy, just enough to categorize the images by dominant and sub-dominant colors. Thanks!

Comment: How many buckets / colours you are selecting at the beginning? This can be a little tricky.

Comment: If the bucketing part complicates things, an answer which aggregates colors to very broad averages would get me in the right direction. Something similar to #0000FF:90%, #FFFFFF:10%

Comment: This should be tagged `algorithm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

1) Define a set of colours which we'll call centroids -- these are the middle of the basic colours you want to break images into. You can do this using a clustering algorithm like [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), for example. So now you've got, say, 100 centroids (buckets, you can think of them as), each of which is an RGB colour triple with a name you can manually attach to it.

2) To generate the histogram for a new image:

- open the image in [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or whatever
- convert it to an array of pixel values (e.g. using [imagecolorat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php))
- determine the distance ([euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) is ok) between the pixel value and all the centroids. Classify each pixel as to which bucket it's closest to.
- Your output is a centroid assignment for each pixel. Or, given you just want a histogram, you can just count how many times each centroid occurs.

Bear in mind that this kind of colour assignment is somewhat subjective. I'm not sure there'll be a definitive mapping from colours to names (e.g., it's [language dependent](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Through-Language-Glass-Words-Colour/dp/043401690X)). But if you google, there might exist a look-up table that you could use, although I've not come across one.

Hope this helps!

Ben

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Do you think that a three-dimensional euclidian distance (r,g,b) would be accurate for mapping pixel colors to the centroids or are you aware of any color measurement calculation that takes human perception into account?

Comment: It's a good question... These links might be helpful: http://99designs.com/tech-blog/blog/2012/05/11/color-analysis/    and   (rather more technical): http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ofirpele/publications/ECCV2010.pdf